# The method findOneAndUpdate change the id of my element in a array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm working with **mongoDB, mongoose and graphQL**. I'm trying to make an update in my DB.

I'm doing an update in an array called phones, the changes work perfectly, the only problem is that when the update ends, the value of the objectId changes.

***// Models -> Schema Organization***

```
const organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
 name: String,
 address: String,
 phones: [
  {
   number: Number,
   prefix: Number
  }
 ],
 email: String
})
```

***// Types -> Organization***

```
type Response {
    success: Boolean!
    token: String   
    errors: [Error]
}

type Error {
    path: String!
    message: String!
}

input iOrganization {
    _id: ID
    arrID: ID
    address: String        
    email: String        
    number: Int
    prefix: Int
    name: String
}

type Mutation {      
    updateOrgGeneric(iOrg: iOrganization): Response!
}
```

**// Resolvers -> Organization (1st way)**

```
Mutation: {
    updateOrgGeneric:  (parent, args, {models}) => {      
        return models.Organization.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "_id": args.iOrg._id, "phones._id": args.iOrg.arrID },
            {  $set: { "phones.$": { number: args.iOrg.number, prefix: args.iOrg.prefix }} },
            {new: true}                
        )
        .then((resp) => {         
            console.log(resp);

            return {
                success: true,
                errors: []
            }  
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return {
                success: false,
                errors: error
            };    
        })
    },
}
```

**// Resolvers -> Organization (2nd way)**

```
Mutation: {
    updateOrgGeneric:  (parent, args, {models}) => {      
        return models.Organization.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "_id": args.iOrg._id },
            {  $set: { "phones.$[arr]": { number: args.iOrg.number, prefix: args.iOrg.prefix }} },
            {new: true}
            { arrayFilters:[{ "arr._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.iOrg.arrID) }], new: true}                
        )
        .then((resp) => {         
            console.log(resp);

            return {
                success: true,
                errors: []
            }  
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return {
                success: false,
                errors: error
            };    
        })
    }
}
```

***// Playground (http://localhost:5000/graphql)***

```
mutation {
 updateOrgGeneric(
   iOrg: {
    _id: "5bdbee1b794b972bc8562aeb"             
    arrID: "5bdcea7cae88be098c020b19"
    number: 85239,
    prefix: 862 
   }
 ){
   success
   errors {
    path
    message
   }
 }
}
```

Both _id, as arrID, exist in the BD.

In the playground example the initial arrID was: _id:ObjectId("5bdcea7cae88be098c020b19"), but after the update is another, example: _id:ObjectId("5bdcec0a2ab78533b4bd1d98"). What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is a nosql database which means that every object in the database should consist of an Id and revision values. Once an update occurs the revision value changes as part of the update process to implement the changes made to the data object. Since your data object don't have the revision value then the id value changes. Because it is unique. Now I'm no expert with mongo but you should check the docs on how to persist data objects and change accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Normally I don't have problems when updating a document in mongo, it doesn't change the id. The problem comes when dealing with an arrangement of subdocuments, I do the same process, but I get different results. I'll continue reading the documentation although until now I don't find anything, I think it is something that I do wrong in my code, but I don't know ..

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone lands here (despite this being old post), the problem probably lies in trying to update the entire `phones` object, of which the overwritten `_id` is a part. Since there's a model defined for `phones`in mongoose, it will try to create a new `_id` any time an entire new `phones` object is created.

Someone who wanted to keep the same id would need to `$set` only the fields they want to change, rather than the entire object. So

```
{  $set: { "phones.$[arr]": { number: args.iOrg.number, prefix: args.iOrg.prefix }} }
```

could be changed to

```
{  $set: { "phones.$[arr].number": args.iOrg.number, "phones.$[arr].prefix": args.iOrg.prefix } }
```